# How to prevent combining 2 boxplots into 1 on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I am trying to create a plot with 6 panels showing two boxplots (representing the effect of injury (1 = presence of injury, 0 = absence of injury). The closest I have gotten is this:

```
ggplot(cell_measurement, aes(Injury, Acceleration_mean)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=.3, aes(fill = Injury)) + 
  geom_jitter(size=0.1)+
  facet_grid(vars(Animal))
```

Which has produced:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDHKe.png)

The data looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi1qZ.png)

What it has instead done is merged the Injury to make 0.5 but my issue is that the 0 and 1 group are two distinct groups I am trying to represent on each panel. I have tried changing the Injury groups into 'Presence' and 'Absence' but everything I have tried has not worked.

Any suggestions on how to go about this, please?

Thank you!

(sorry I have not been on here long enough to post actual images)

Comment: The plot you show does not match the code you post. In your code, `Animal` is on the x-axis. On your plot, `Injury` appears to be on the x-axis. Please clarify what you want, what you have, and share a little bit of sample data in a copy/pasteable way, such as `dput(df[1:10, ])`.

Comment: Please post the data you are using to make the plot in your question, thanks!

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you, sorry so nervous about my first post. I believe I have rectified it now.

Comment: @Skaqqs I have done that now, thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! You could try replacing injury with as.factor(injury)

Comment: Instead of using `fill`, use `group`. i.e. `geom_boxplot(alpha=.3, aes(group = Injury))`. You could still use fill if you want to stylize, but ggplot needs to know that you want to separate Injury for the boxplot.

Comment: @TrainingPizza I love you. You are amazing and I have never EVER been so happy in my life. I hope you are going to have a great weekend starting from right now.

Comment: @user345995 lol, glad it worked. Have a great weekend :)

Comment: Glad to hear this got worked out. In the future, please don't post pictures of data--post it as copy/pasteable text. `dput()` makes this easy and includes all class and structure information, e.g., `dput(df[1:10, ])` to share the first 10 rows of `df`.